When is de/d' only used in front of a noun, especially abstract/uncountable nouns?
I have looked for an answer to this question but have found nothing anywhere and it's driving me crazy frankly. Is there a formula I can follow easily?
Like here it's "moyens de communication". Why not du?

Oui, c’est vrai que les gens utilisent de moins en moins de moyens de communication physiques tels que les lettres...

And here, why not "de l'utilisation"?

Ces concepts d'utilisation de la technologie ...

And yet here, why not "de sujets":

...dans le contexte des sujets qui sont présentés dans l'examen

And why not "manque de la motivation"

le genre de personnes qui manquent de motivation pour continuer
(talking about not continuing to go to the gym)

My French tutor gave me a rule which is 'de+le+nom' (use definite article if the sentence ends with the noun) and 'de+nom+other info' (do not use definite article if there is other info after the noun). Is there a rule like this? If so, then does it only apply to abstract nouns?

While the details are different in French, much of the same underlying logic applies as in English: why means of communication (not means of the communication)? Why in the context of the topics that appear on the exam (not of topics that appear)? In both cases, the other option could be used if context warranted it – the last one particularly works perfectly well either way, depending on whether we’re talking about topics in general or about a specific set of topics already referred to.

The uncountable thing can be de, des, or d'. Whereas "de l'eau" is a partitive, some water. Your examples are all non-partitives. They do not mean "some" or "any". Also, bear in mind that when there is not a usual adjective in French to accompany an uncountable noun (like the adjective communicationnel) the de + noun is preferred: moyens de communications. In this respect and in cases like these, it's like English. means of survival, moyens de survie. Your French tutor is right re nouns with de + a noun like moyens de communication.

As so often happens in grammar, the real rule is easy to state, but it's hard to recognize the situations where it applies. This is why teachers and tutors come up with tons of "heuristic rules" that are easy to spot and mostly correlate with the real one, but aren't foolproof and don't provide real insight.
The rule is: use the definite article only if the noun following the de is definite. Simple, right? :/
My favourite heuristic rules are:

No article if the second noun qualifies the first — if it narrows down what kind it is. For example: moyens de communication describes a type of moyen, specifically the ones related to communication.

No article if the first noun is a container or an amount. For example: beaucoup de personnes or une bouteille d'eau.

But do use the article if the second noun is a specific set of things and the first one picks out some of them. For example: there are certain sujets présentés dans l'examen. In the context of those specific subjects: dans le contexte des sujets ... Or compare these two sentences:



Beaucoup d'étudiants trouvent l'apprentissage d'une langue difficile.
= Lots of students find learning a language hard.


Beaucoup des étudiants à cette école trouvent l'apprentissage d'une langue difficile.
= Lots of the students [in this school] find learning a language hard.

Also see Frank's notes in the comments that (1) the second one feels odd standing on its own — it needs that specification of which students, and (2) the context could lead to the first one covering either meaning.

Your last example is actually a different rule, though. This rule is that typically after a negative — specifically the lack of existence of a thing — de is preferred. This is the case with manquer de X.

I'm not sure beaucoup des étudiants could sound broken, at least for me. I would be uncomfortable enough to switch to eg beaucoup des étudiants ici. Also, the first sentence could be used with the value of the second one, relying on the context to bridge the difference.

@Frank Agreed on both points — the second example would have to work in a context where we know we're talking about this set of students.

The main reason is that none of those are partitives, right?
